# using csrf_token in django widget

Tags: django

I am trying to make a custom django widget with ajax. The ajax call requires csrf_token.
I need to know how to pass the csrf_token to the widget html.

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from widgets import MyWidget

class PenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    color = forms.CharField(widget=MyWidget)
    class Media:
        js = (
            'js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
            'js/jquery-ui.min.js',
        )
        css = {
            'all': (
                'css/jquery-ui.min.css',
            )
        }


# widgets.py
from django.forms.widgets import Widget
from django.template import loader
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class MyWidget(Widget):
    template_name = 'my_widget.html'
    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs={}):
        return {'widget': {
            'name': name,
            'value': value,
            'attrs': attrs,
            'csrf_token': '???'
        }}

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
        template = loader.get_template(self.template_name).render(context)
        return mark_safe(template)
```

Here is my widget html:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#autocomplete_{{ widget.name }}" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: "/get_colors",
          type: "post",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
          data: {
            term: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        } );
      },
      minLength: 1,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log.debug( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " , " + ui.item.id );
      }
    } );
  } );
</script>


# admin.py
@admin.register(Pen)
class PenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PenForm
    list_display = ['label', 'color']
```

I already tried using {{ csrf_token }} which does not work so I'm thinking that I should get the token from the admin get_queryset(self, request) and pass it to the form and then pass it to the widget then to the template.
If this theory is right, then I need to know how to pass the token to the widget.

Comment: Have you tried removing 'csrf_token': '???' from context?

Comment: See the [ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax) section of the docs. If you get the token from the cookie, then you don't need to output `{{ csrf_token }}` in the template.

Comment: Great. Retrieving it from cookies worked. Thanks.